# Canvas animation progress

Tags: jquery, animation, canvas

I am using this jQuery circular progress bar (https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) in trying to create a pomodoro timer. Using the documentation, I know that I can pause the progress bar like this

```
var el = $('.pomProgressTimer');
$(el.circleProgress('widget')).stop();
```

and I can redraw the progress bar on resume from the progress it already made.

```
var obj = $('.pomProgressTimer').data('circle-progress'),
ctx = obj.ctx,
progress = ctx.canvas.animationProgress;
$('.pomProgressTimer').circleProgress({
    animationStartValue: progress,
  });
```

However, this only works when you pause the progress bar the first time. When I resume the progress bar, let it run a bit, pause it again, and try to resume it, animationProgress is stuck at the value it was at the first time.

I've been looking up pausing and resuming canvas animation but none of the proposed solutions seem to work.

It looks like using the pause method from the documentation freezes the animationProgress. Is there another way to pause this?

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anthkris/jeycb92x/87/

Comment: Works like a charm here... Not using an outdated browser?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 47. So the pause works. The thing is that when you click resume, let it run, pause it and then resume again, it starts from an old value, not from where the progress bar is after the second pause, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was too hasty with my comment.

You can use the `lastFrameValue` from the object to resume the circle, like this:

```
var obj = $('.pomProgressTimer').data('circle-progress'),
    progress = obj.lastFrameValue;
```

Full fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeycb92x/88/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been working on this for three days with no success.

Comment: Should've come to us earlier then ;)